# Javascript: Passing JSON requests to a new page

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am generating nearest Google Places locations based on a user's geolocation here:

http://sandrayoon.com/UAI/www3/placesstyle.php

When one clicks on a location name, it is creating a dynamic url to request JSON from Google Places for details about the location:

```
a.href = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference="+place.reference+"&sensor=true&key=xxxxxxxxxxx";
    a.innerHTML = place.name;
```

This URL is just a request for JSON, but what I need is that when the user clicks a location they are taken to another page that begins to process the JSON.

How can I pass this JSON request to a new page that then processes the JSON from Google Places with a user click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to obtain that JSON data and processing it right there in the page, without navigating away?

Comment: Yep, I've been having problems with the Google Places API cross-domain request issue (since JSONP is not allowed). Is there a way to use AJAX requests within the javascript API?

Comment: They provide an API to do this: https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#PlacesService

Answer (score 1):

If you want a *dedicated page* for displaying place details, you will need to create a new page, with a URL that contains the place reference. From there, you can use AJAX to call the Google JSON URL and process the place details.

http://sandrayoon.com/UAI/www3/places.php?reference=place_reference

So, with a URL like above, you can retrieve the place `reference' and build the proper Google Places JSON URL. You can then issue an AJAX request against that URL to process the JSON response.